# How do i make paging using jquery ajax for rhomobile app

Tags: jquery, ajax, rhomobile, rhodes

I have a table where i need to show records in pagination manner.

Let say i have 200 records, i need to show 10 records on each page. I have used [Paginate](http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodesapi/rhom-api#paginate) to get data from Rhom.

```
  MyModel.paginate(:page => 1, :per_page => 10)
```

So how can i use the ajax call to fetch the next page records without changing the view.

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have the ajax call to a method by sending the page number and page limit, and get the view through responce.

You should make the view to have the exact design as you have in you original view, and after ajax success, just replace the view with the new one.

```
$.get('/app/MyModel/get_new_view, 
    { pageNumber: 1,  // u need to set it dynamically
      pageLimit: 10 }
    )
    .success( function ( data ) {

        // Check the Responce
        if(data.length != 0) {
            $('.container').html(data);
        }
        else {
            alert('Unable to get the page');
        }
    })
    .error ( function ( data ) {
        alert('Unable to get the page');
    });
```

**Suggession**

If you want to reduce the burden of writing such code, you can simply get all the records in the view and use [JqueryDataTable](https://datatables.net/) to render them as like you want.

```
$(document).ready( function () {
     $('.youTable').dataTable({
       "aaSorting": [[ 1, "asc" ]],
       "aoColumnDefs": [{ "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 0,1 ] }]
     });
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for the ajax call. I copied my table view to another methods view and made a ajax call to it. Secondly, datatable looks brilliant. Would surely like to give this a try.

Comment: Yes, even you can have your own css code to override there table style.